# Why does this alias not work in .bash_profile script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, alias, chromium

I'm trying to write a bash alias for `Chromium` on my Mac OSX.  It works when it's not in a bash aliases script, but it doesn't work when I try to create an alias.

I tried these commands in my terminal, one after the other:

```
cd /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/
./Chromium --pro-server="socks5://localhost:1234
cd -
```

Then, I tried to put these all into one alias command in my `.bash_profile` script:

```
alias launch_chromium='cd /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/; ./Chromium --pro-server="socks5://localhost:1234" ; cd -'
```

Now, when I launch bash like this: `bash --login`, I get

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

And, when I copy and paste what exactly what is in the alias command into the terminal, and it works perfectly:L

```
cd /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/; ./Chromium --pro-server="socks5://localhost:1234" ; cd -
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put the `alias` definition within double quotes?

Comment: In general, btw, `.bash_profile` is run only for login shells. Not all interactive shells are login shells, and aliases aren't inherited through the environment, so you really should be putting alias definitions in `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: Note that in macOS, though, terminal emulators tend to start login shells, so it becomes more useful to make sure `.bashrc` is sourced from `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I'd consider running your whole `.bash_profile` through http://shellcheck.net/, by the way -- that should identify where your syntax error is, since it doesn't actually appear to be in this alias.

Comment: What are reasons to run a `non-login` shell instead of a `login` shell?

Comment: Can your run your .bash_profile through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)? I guess you have somewhere an open single quote.

Comment: I'm using a `Mac OSX`, and the default is for it to launch a login shell upon startup, so that's why I have my aliases inside of `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias definition posted in your question does *not* explain your symptom - it should work.

However, your problem is better solved with a shell *function* rather than an alias:

```
launch_chromium() ( 
 cd /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/
 exec ./Chromium --pro-server="socks5://localhost:1234" "$@"
)
```

Note how:

- `( ... )` is used to enclose the function body, which causes it to run in a *subshell*, which obviates the need to return to the previous working dir.
- `exec` is used for efficiency: it *replaces* the subshell with the Chromium process, since the subshell is then no longer needed.<sup>Tip of the hat to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for this and the next point.</sup>
- `"$@"` is appended to pass potential arguments through.

Using a function has two important advantages:

- Invoking it is a *single* command, whereas your alias comprises *multiple* commands, which leads to unexpected behavior in pipelines, for instance.
- A function can accept *arguments* - unlike an alias.

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual need to change the working directory.

```
alias launch_chromium='/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium --pro-server="socks5://localhost:1234"'
```

Comment: Maybe the OP sometimes has their working directory on removable media, and wants to be able to remove it without killing their browser session.